# Select only sites that have credits

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have a traffic exchange site and I have a small problem on the surfing area .

Normally the script should choose only sites that have credits but it does not .

I search on google and here also but I couldn't find my answere .

```
$hour = date('Y-m-d:H');
$res = mysql_query("update site set hour='$hour', cth=0 where hour!='$hour' && cph!=0");
$query = "select id, url from site where usrid!=".$_SESSION['sess_data']['usrid']." && state='Enabled'";
if ($_SESSION['sess_data']['negact'] == 0) {
    $query = $query." && credits>=1";
}
$query = $query." && (cth<cph || cph=0)";
$query = $query." order by rand() limit 1";
$res = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
    $url = $default_site;
    $siteid = 0;
} else {
    $url = mysql_result($res, 0, "url");
    $siteid = mysql_result($res, 0, "id");
}
```

If I'm right this is the part where the script get's the websites .

```
$query = "select id, url from site where usrid!=" . $_SESSION['sess_data']['usrid'] . " && state='Enabled'";
```

In this line I would like to add a limit , to choose sites that have +5 credits. ( Again , If I'm right )

Thanks .

Comment: why are you using PHP to generate a date? `... set hour=now()` and save yourself some php overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE "`WHERE credits > 5`" or whatever your "credits" column is called.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in    , Something is wrong ..

Comment: if ($_SESSION['sess_data']['negact'] == 0) {
    $query = $query." && credits>=1"; << this one should do the same thing right ? I change the record to 10 K but still show's site with lower credits